# woocommerce search by sku and title ajax

Tags: plugins, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax

**This snippet works only in Title and i need to add also in Metakey SKU.**

```
<?php
```

// Ajax Search.

```
function thb_ajax_search() {

check_ajax_referer( 'thb_autocomplete_ajax', 'security' );
$search_keyword              = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'query', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
$time_start                  = microtime( true );
$product_visibility_term_ids = wc_get_product_visibility_term_ids();
$ordering_args               = WC()->query->get_catalog_ordering_args('title', 'asc' );
$suggestions                 = array();
$args = array(
    's'                   => $search_keyword,
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => 3,
    'orderby'             => $ordering_args['orderby'],
    'order'               => $ordering_args['order'],
    'suppress_filters'    => false,
    'meta_key'          => '_sku',

    'tax_query'           => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms'    => $product_visibility_term_ids['exclude-from-search'],
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$products = get_posts( $args );

if ( ! empty( $products ) ) {
    foreach ( $products as $post ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $post );

        $suggestions[] = array(
            'id'        => $product->get_id(),
            'value'     => wp_strip_all_tags( $product->get_title() ),
            'url'       => $product->get_permalink(),
            'thumbnail' => $product->get_image(),
            'price'     => $product->get_price_html(),
            'sku'       => $product->get_sku(),
        );
    }


}

 else {
    $suggestions = false;
}

$time_end    = microtime( true );
$time        = $time_end - $time_start;
$suggestions = array(
    'suggestions' => $suggestions,
    'time'        => $time,
);
echo wp_json_encode( $suggestions );
wp_die();}add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_thb_ajax_search', 'thb_ajax_search' );add_action( 'wp_ajax_thb_ajax_search', 'thb_ajax_search' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pls Try this code**

```
if(is_numeric($search_keyword)){
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page'  => 3,
            'post_type'       => 'product',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_sku',
                    'value' => $search_keyword,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        );
}

else if(is_string($search_keyword)){
  $args = array(
    's'                   => $search_keyword,
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => 3,
    'orderby'             => $ordering_args['orderby'],
    'order'               => $ordering_args['order'],
    'suppress_filters'    => false,
    'tax_query'           => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms'    => $product_visibility_term_ids['exclude-from-search'],
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);}
```

Comment: Grt thanks for help.